# An error that undefined method `user_recent_media' for #<Hashie::Array:0x007fe4c90f39c0> occurred on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to get photos via Instagram with instagram-ruby but the error occurred.

The code is below. As I checked, the program can get a specified user's info.

```
       client = Instagram.user_recent_media(access_token: Auth.find_by(provider:"instagram",id:1).token)
       @medias = client.user_recent_media
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to combine 2 steps into one here. According to the documentation for this gem, it looks like you need to first initialize a client, using:

```
client = Instagram.client(access_token: SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN)`
```

and then afterwards try to fetch the user recent media:

```
@medias = client.user_recent_media
```

It looks like the only thing you've done wrong in your implementation is calling `user_recent_media` on the Instagram gem directly, rather than on the initialized version of it.

TL;DR: This code should work:

```
client = Instagram.client(access_token: Auth.find_by(provider:"instagram",id:1).token)
@medias = client.user_recent_media
```

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to you, I could do what I wanted to get successfully.